How to get a list of chat names that a Telegram bot is a member of using Telegram Bot API?
I am developing a Telegram bot using Node.js and axios to interact with the Telegram Bot API. I need to get a list of all chat names that the bot is a member of. I am able to fetch updates and chat information using the getUpdates and getChat methods. Here is my current code:
const axios = require('axios');

const botToken = process.env.BOT_TOKEN;
const apiUrl = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${'botToken'}`;

const getUpdates = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/getUpdates`);
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err
  }
};
const getChat = async (chatId) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/getChat`, {
        params: {
            chat_id: chatId,
        },
    });
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err
  }
}

module.exports = {getUpdates, getChat}

How can I get a list of all chats that the bot is a member of using the getUpdates method?
How can I extract the names of these chats?
At the moment, I am receiving updates but am not entirely sure how to properly extract chat information and its name from the data received. What is the best way to do this? Are there any potential issues or limitations when obtaining this information?
I would appreciate any help!

Simple answer - you can't. Telegram Bot API currently does not provide any method to list all the chats that your bot is part of. You have to keep track of this yourself.
How to?
You can primarily listen to two updates to keep track of the new chats with their ids.

Whenever a new user is interacting with your bot they'll most probably start with /start command. So, whenever you get a /start Message update check if the Message.chat.id is already saved to your database if not save it.

Whenever your bot is added to a group/supergroup/channel your bot will receive a my_chat_member update of type ChatMemberUpdated. Check the new_chat_member and old_chat_member statuses to figure out if the bot was added or removed from the chat then save/delete the ChatMemberUpdated.chat.id to your database.



Once you have the chat_ids with you (on your database), you can simply do getChat calls to get the chat's name and further details.
Hope this helps!
